# Trying to understand how a pointer return type works

Tags: c++, pointers, return-value, return-type

I'm trying to understand how returning a pointer works in the following scenarios:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Why does this work? I can even pass the return value to another function
// and the contents do not change.
char* StringFromFunction()
{
  char* pReturn = "This string was created in the function.";
  return pReturn;
}

// I know this is wrong because the memory address where 5 is stored can be
// overwritten.
int* IntegerFromFunction()
{
  int returnValue = 5;
  return &returnValue;
}

int main()
{
  int*  pInteger;
  char* pString;

  pString = StringFromFunction();
  pInteger = IntegerFromFunction();

  cout << *pInteger << endl << pString << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The program output is as I expect it to be:

```
5
This string was created in the function.
```

The only compiler warning I get in Visual C++ 2010 Express is "**c:\vc2010projects\test\main.cpp(14): warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary**" and it only shows when I use `IntegerFromFunction()` and not `StringFromFunction()`.

What I think I am understanding from the examples above is the following:

Inside `StringFromFunction()`, the memory allocation for the text "This string was created in the function." occurs at execution time and because it is a string literal, the contents persist in memory even after the function returns, and that is why the pointer `pString` in `main()` can be passed to another function and the string can be displayed within it.

However, for `IntegerFromFunction()`, when the function returns the memory allocated is now freed and therefore, that memory address can be overwritten.

I guess my main questions is, can pointers that point to string literals safely be passed around throughout the program?

Comment: also try: char* StringFromFunction()
{
  char[] pReturn = "This string was created in the function.";
  return pReturn;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to see the difference is to generate the dissasembly of a simple hello-world-ish example:

```
char* test() {
 return "Test";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
 return 0;
}
```

This is the diassembly with gcc in FreeBSD with optimization turned off

```
    .file   "hellow.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "test"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
.globl test
    .type   test, @function
test:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    popl    %ebp
    ret
    .size   test, .-test
    .p2align 4,,15
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    leal    4(%esp), %ecx
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   -4(%ecx)
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ecx
    call    test
    movl    $0, %eax
    popl    %ecx
    popl    %ebp
    leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.2.1 20070719  [FreeBSD]"
```

As you can see, the string literal itself was stored in the .LC0 section, not in the code itself. The test function just return a pointer to the beginning of .LC0 (movl $.LC0, %eax) as this is the first string literal. The location is similar (but not the same) depending the executable format you are compiling to. Read [A.out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out) (text segment), or [PE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable).

Comment: This might be interesting too, but a little bit more advanced: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/dataseg.html

Comment: Thanks for this. You just helped me to understand a lot of the answers. For example, now I know what rodata is referring to, and now I can see how there is an area in the executable where the string literals are actually stored and the function didn't actually create the string literal. This leads me to another question. Does this mean that I can access the string literal without ever calling the function?

Comment: Yes you can in the same sense as you can access any global variables without ever referencing them (they would go into the .data segment) - without optimization. I'm not sure though that compiler wouldn't optimize them away if enabled - as it wouldn't include test function if not called ever. It would be difficult to access it though as you don't have a pointer to it. You would need some dirty tricks or inlined assembly.

Answer (score 4):

String literals are not actually stored on the stack for the function like automatic variables are, but are stored on a special location (like global variables).

Note that writing to them is not portable, so it is best to use them as `const char *` and not `char *`.

Comment: Is this "special location" part of the heap, or is it separate from stack/heap altogether?

Comment: @The111 Seperate. It's a special section in the executable, like the code section. In ELF files (used in Linux and other places), it's called `.rodata`. See sarnold's answer for more info.

Comment: @The111 They are usually stored in the read-only section of the executable.

Answer (score 3):

When I compile your program, I get an additional warning from `g++`, my compiler:

```
$ make strings
g++     strings.cc   -o strings
strings.cc: In function ‘char* StringFromFunction()’:
strings.cc:8:19: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
strings.cc: In function ‘int* IntegerFromFunction()’:
strings.cc:16:7: warning: address of local variable ‘returnValue’ returned
```

To avoid the warning, add `const` in front of the declaration of the variable, the return type of the function, and the variable in the `main()` function.

The GNU toolchain will store the `This string was created in the function.` string in the `.rodata` read-only data section, which is valid for the lifetime of the program:

```
$ readelf -p .rodata strings

String dump of section '.rodata':
  [     8]  This string was created in the function.
```

Of course, you cannot *modify* the contents of the string, but that is usually fine for strings statically compiled into the program.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing to understand is the *lifetime* of the object that you're returning a pointer to (actually, object lifetime is a key thing to understand about pretty much any object instance).  the C standard uses the terminology of 'storage duration' for object lifetime, since in C an object is literally a region of data storage that represents values.

A string literal has 'static storage duration', which means (C99 6.2.4/3):

> Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.

So there's no problem returning a pointer to a string literal from a function (as far as the lifetime of the object the pointer refers to goes). The string literal object will always be a valid object. One thing to be careful of is that the returned pointer will allow someone to try to modify the array of data containing the string literal, which is not permitted (it's undefined behavior).

The local `int returnValue` variable in the other example has 'automatic storage duration' which means (C99 6.2.4/4):

> its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in any way

(note that the lifetime of an automatic variable length array is slightly different).

So, the pointer to `returnValue` becomes invalid the moment the function returns.

I think that object lifetime is one of the fundamental things that every programmer should understand, and it's particularly important in C and C++ since the programmer is largely responsible for handling it correctly especially when dealing with pointers.

Comment: +1 for properly describing _why_ the behavior is the way it is instead of just dissecting _what_ some arbitrary implementation's behavior is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pointers to string literals are safe to be passed around, as long as you only read from them. This is because they basically are statically allocated by the compiler, kind of like this:

```
/* global/static variables go in the data section at compile time, not in the stack*/
char myString[6] = {'a', ' ',  'l', 'i', 't', '\0'};

char* StringFromFunction()
{
  char* pReturn = &myString[0]; //this pointer is not actually to inside this function!
  return pReturn; 
}
```

If you want to blow things up try allocating an actual array in the function instead of getting a pointer to the string literal.

```
char* StringFromFunction()
{
    char myString[6] = {'a', ' ',  'l', 'i', 't', '\0'};
    return &myString[0];
}
```

---

Do note that string literals are constant and read only. You should not try to write to or update them, lest you fall upon undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

String literals like `"This string was created in the function."` are placed into read-only memory. You're only allowed to assign them to a `char *` for backwards compatibility, it's more proper to use `const char *` which accurately reflects their nature.